# Print multidimensional array to table

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, html-table

I have a array like this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 109
            [label] => c
            [quantity] => 12
            [unit] => g
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 120
            [label] => c
            [quantity] => 12
            [unit] => g
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 119
            [label] => b
            [quantity] => 200
            [unit] => oz
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 118
            [label] => b
            [quantity] => 200
            [unit] => oz
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121
            [label] => b
            [quantity] => 10
            [unit] => g
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I have to print like

```html
<table>
<tr><td>c</td><td>c</td><td></td><td></td><td>b</td></tr>
<tr><td>b</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td>b</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

what I tried is,

```
foreach($final_array as $food_array){
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$food_array[0]['label'].'</td>';
echo '<tr>';
}
```

but it seems not working, can anyone help in this?

Comment: it would be better if you clean & merge arrays into single array if its same in array dimensions write only one `foreach`. Just for clean code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code you should try,

```
foreach ($final_array as $food_array) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($food_array as $key1 => $value1) {
        echo '<td>' . $value1['label'] . '</td>';    
    }
    echo '<tr>';
}
```

You need to loop it twice to get your output.